# What does the ??-operator do?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am moving through codes while using Flutter. I saw the operator `??` which I could not understand.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
id = prefs.getString('id') ?? '';
nickname = prefs.getString('nickname') ?? '';
aboutMe = prefs.getString('aboutMe') ?? '';
photoUrl = prefs.getString('photoUrl') ?? '';
```

Comment: The name of this operator is Null coalescing operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator

Comment: You can  read more about [here](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb)

Answer (score 1):

It is commonly called null-coalescing operator...at least on C#.

You can find a lot of information on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

And as detailed on that link

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null

Answer (score 1):

`??` is one of the **Null-aware Operator** in **Dart**

`result = leftSideValue ?? rightSideValue`

It checks whether left side value is null. if the left side value is null, then it assigns default (right side) value to result.

Example 1

```
var data1;
var data2 = data1 ?? "Default value";
print(data2); // Default value
```

Example 2

```
var data1 = "Some Value";
var data2 = data1 ?? "Default value";
print(data2); // Some value
```

You can read more about it in [Dart Docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) & [Medium](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yes its one of the 'Null-Aware operator'. Not from his article, from [dart document](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) itself.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

```
<Expression>??<Value if expression is null>;
```

Example of ??

int a;
int b = a??0;

This assigns the value of '0' to 'b', because 'a' is null. This can be rewritten as,

```
int a;
int b;
if(a==null){
  b=0;
}else{
  b=a;
}
```